# Problem with email notification on Google Sheet linked to Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I need that when a specific answer is given in a google form (is one option of a multiple choise), an email informing that event be send.

### The code is:

```
function activadorPrueba() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger('notificarMailVencido')
.forForm('*[googleFormIdIsHere]*')
.onFormSubmit()
.create();
 }

function notificarMailVencido(e){
if ( e.range.columnStart != 6 || e.value != "Si, pero está vencida") return;
let patente = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
let msg = "El vehiculo patente " + patente + " tiene la poliza vencida.";
MailApp.sendEmail("*[mailHere]*","aviso poliza", msg)}
```

---

The problem is that when a google form is send, and error saying the next occurs:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'columnStart')"

If i only use the function "notificarMailVencido" and a onEdit activator, the function works without problem when editing the Google Sheet, but the problem starts when try to execute with the google form trigger.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the type of trigger you set on your script, the methods to access the values from the event are different.

I see that you have set an onFormSubmit trigger that captures the Form Event, but in the "function notificarMailVencido(e)" you are using methods that are related to the Sheet Event, which is a different trigger.

I suggest you look into [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to better understand which methods you can use depending on which trigger you have set.

Taking that into account, I recommend you set a sheet Trigger in the sheet that you get the Form responses, like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")//replace this with the function you want the trigger to call.
.forSpreadsheet(sheet)
.onFormSubmit()
.create();
```

Once you have done that part, you can access now all values from the onFormSubmit event by calling the following methods in your custom function:

1. e.values; //Array with values in the same order as they appear in the spreadsheet.
2. e.namedValues; //An object containing the question names and values from the form submission.